# Dual boot PrimeOS from another disk

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I am a new on Ubuntu. I wanna dual boot the PrimeOS system which is installed on another drive.

I have tried using GRUB Customizer but I just cannot get the command right.

Can somebody please help me with the apt command for selecting the OS from another drive in GRUB Customizer.

Path where PrimeOS is currently located: `/dev/sdb1/PrimeOS`

Current commands:

```
insmod part_gpt
search --file --no-floppy --set=root /home/Home/PrimeOS/system.sfs
linux /home/Home/PrimeOS/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug SRC=/home/Home/PrimeOS
initrd /home/Home/PrimeOS/initrd.img
```

Comment: How did you mount /dev/sdb1?  in /home. Probably better not to be in /home. And then where is extra /home/Home. Check how you have it mounted. post this: `mount` just need one line with PrimeOS mount.

Comment: Okay so here is my exact drive address where prime os is installed.
/dev/sdb1
This drive is in "Other locations" Named "PrimeOS

Comment: Is that a label so automounted by label or a mount point. But your boot stanza is before any mounts take place as system has not started. So you have to have path as seen before any mount. Or if sdab1 has one folder /PrimeOS, then path is (hd1,1)/PrimeOS. No /home as /home has yet to be mounted by system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot up Ubuntu and run the following command to automatically detect the other operating system and this should automatically update grub for you:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When you reboot, the PrimeOS operating system should show on the list of available operating systems.

Comment: Sorry that did not solve the problem, It still did not recognized the prime os

Comment: @huzaifaimran Is the sdb drive mounted? If so, unmount the drive before you update grub.

Comment: @huzaifaimran Actually, [this might be what you are looking for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519867/70847) but instead of `hd0,2` you will have to use something else, I assume it would be `hd1,1` because primeos is on `sdb1` but you will have to check to verify. Also, where the answer says "from Debian" it will mean "from Ubuntu" in your case.